# image won't show even after image.Show()

Tags: python, wxpython

Code below.

If you execute the program as is (just change "moresco.jpg" to any image on your computer), it will first show a black square, and if you click on the search button the image you hardcoded (moresco.jpg in my case) will be displayed.

What I want is to hide the black square at startup and show moresco.jpg when I click on search. So I thought of putting a .Show() over there.

If you uncomment line 22, the black square doesn't show (which is what we want), but then when you click on search moresco.jpg doesn't show.

If you have any suggestions on how to fix this code I would be grateful !

```
import wx
class gui(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button = wx.Button(self,-1,"search")
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.display,button)
        hsizer1.Add(button,.1,wx.EXPAND)
        vsizer.Add(hsizer1,.1,wx.EXPAND)
        hsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        vsizer.Add(hsizer2,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.pnl=wx.Panel(self)
        img = wx.EmptyImage(500,500)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.pnl, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                         wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        # uncomment this line and the image won't show even after
        # click on search button
        #-----------------------------
        # print self.imageCtrl.Hide()
        #-----------------------------

        hsizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hsizer3.Add(self.pnl,2,wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL,wx.EXPAND)
        vsizer.Add(hsizer3,2,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(vsizer)
        self.pnl.Layout()

    def display(self,strip):
        self.Refresh()
        self.Update()
        self.imageCtrl.Refresh()
        self.imageCtrl.Update()         
        print self.imageCtrl.Show()
        self.imageCtrl.Refresh()
        self.imageCtrl.Update()        
        self.Refresh()
        self.Update()
        imageFile = "moresco.jpg"
        jpg1 = wx.Image(imageFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        # bitmap upper left corner is in the position tuple (x, y) = (5, 5)
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(jpg1))
        self.Refresh()
        self.Update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    w,h=wx.DisplaySize()
    frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, id=-1, title="transmorgripy",size=(w/1.2,h/1.2 ))
    frame.Center()
    panel = gui(frame)

    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Hide()` and `Show()` on a control does not simply set it to being transparent or not. When it is hidden it does not have a place in its parent panel's `Sizer`. After you show the image control, it needs a chance to be fit into the parent panel. Depending on exactly how you want it to be displayed you may want to call [Fit](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#Fit) or [Layout](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#Layout).

To show the image and trigger the `Sizer` giving it a position you could do something like this:

```
def display(self, strip):
    print self.imageCtrl.Show()
    imageFile = "moresco.jpg"
    jpg1 = wx.Image(imageFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    # bitmap upper left corner is in the position tuple (x, y) = (5, 5)
    self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(jpg1))
    self.Layout()
```